# How to put a string inside a char* variable in c++

Tags: c++, string, char, addition

well I'm going to be brief here.
I have this variable:

`char* String;`

and a function:

```
void AddString(char str[])
{

}
```

And I need to add the str to String at the end of it for example:
if `String = "ABC"`
and `str = "123"`
after the function AddString `String = "ABC123"`
I searched all over the web, but I couldn't find what I need, any help?

Answer (score 4):

In C++, use `std::string` rather than C-style character arrays:

```
#include <string>

std::string String;
void AddString(std::string str) {
    String += str;
}
```

If you really want to do that by steam, then you'll need to allocate a large enough array for the result, copy the strings in, and remember to put a terminator (zero-valued character) after the end. C library functions like `strlen`, `strcpy` and `strcat` might be useful. The details are left as an exercise, since the question is about C++ not C.

Answer (score 3):

For using C strings you have functions inside the cstring header file. To concatenate strings you have [strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)

Answer (score 1):

use strcat to combine the two char*

strcat takes two parameters, the destination char array c1 and the source char array c2.
You need to be sure that c1 is big enough to hold all the char from c1 and c2.

However you could use c++ strings. and the + operator will handle this for you.

```
string s1, s2;
string s3 = s1+s2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* String;

void AddString(char str[])
{
    strcat(String , str);
}

/*Also, make sure you have allocated space for String before using AddString*/
String = malloc(25*sizeof(char)); //25 just an example.
```

Also, since this is tagged for C++

You should be using `std::string` instead as shown in other answers